# Concatenate big numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, slice

Let's assume I have some NumPy arrays `a` and `b` where `a.shape` is `(N, 5000)` and `b.shape` is `(N, 2500)`. `N` is some number of samples which may vary based on my problem/algorithm - but its always the same for `a` and `b`.

Now I want another array `c` of shape `(N, 7500)` which holds `a`'s values in `[0:5000]` and `b`'s values in `[5000:7500]`.

Currently I am creating a zero-filled buffer array and slice the values into it:

```
# ...retrieving a
# ...retrieving b
c = zeros.((N, 7500)).astype(np.float32)

# insert values of a
c[:, 0:5000] = a

# insert values of b
c[:, 5000:7500] = b

# free up memory
del a, b
```

Is this a fast / efficient, (and therefore "pythonic" / "numpy'ish") way to do so? Or do **better solutions in terms of space/memory consumption or computing time** exist?

`a` and `b` are loaded from somewhere else and preprocessed, so it is no option to somehow directly insert the data into a buffer `c` without creating `a` and `b`.

Comment: For 2d arrays like this `hstack` is just `concatenate` on axis=1; `concatenate` is compiled code, but from I understand of it, it just doing what you are doing - allocating a receiver and copying value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c = np.hstack([a,b])` would do what you want. See also [np.concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate)

---

Timeit results

```
a = np.ones((1000,5000), dtype=np.float64)
b = np.ones((1000,2500), dtype=np.float64)

%timeit c = np.concatenate([a,b], axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 66.4 ms per loop

%timeit c = np.hstack([a,b])
1000 loops, best of 3: 67.3 ms per loop

# Check that it is really the same:
np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.concatenate([a,b], axis=1), np.hstack([a,b]))
```

So concatenate is probably a bit faster because `hstack` is just a wrapper (unnecessary function call) around `concatenate`

As reference

```
%%timeit
c = np.zeros((1000, 7500), dtype=np.float64)

# insert values of a
c[:, 0:5000] = a

# insert values of b
c[:, 5000:7500] = b

1000 loops, best of 3: 69.7 ms per loop
```

seems almost as fast as `concatenate`. But that's only because the first axis was `1000`. If I change the first axis to only contain `10` elements the timings are completly different:

```
a = np.ones((10,5000), dtype=np.float64)
b = np.ones((10,2500), dtype=np.float64)

# concatenate
1000 loops, best of 3: 349 µs per loop
# hstack
1000 loops, best of 3: 406 µs per loop
# your approach
1000 loops, best of 3: 452 µs per loop
```

Comment: Would you add an example & performance test with concatenate? I had to experiment quite a lot to get what I want with concatenate...so I dumped it and implemented the slicing approach ^^

Comment: I've added also a short discussion about how the number of elements in the first axis influences the timings. So if your ``N`` is very high you probably want to use your approach if it is small you might use ``numpy.concatenate``.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea why my approach is getting faster with higher N? Wouldn't have expected that..

Comment: I just found that out myself when I compared the speeds to those in @MikeMüller s answer. I have no definite answer but it's probably just the overhead of the function call. (One has to transfer large data to a function - that sometimes comes at a price)

Comment: Actually upon further investigation it seems like it was just a statistical fluke. Another test with 1000 test runs for ``timeit`` showed that your approach was marginally slower than the ``concatenate``.

Answer (score 3):

For these sizes, it would be reasonable to just use [hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What do you mean by "for these sizes"? What if the arrays would be really small or much bigger? Are there alternatives to ``hstack`` or the OPs approach?

Comment: You could create an empty (as opposed to null) array `c` of the right size.  Fetch `a`, partially fill `c`, and delete `a`.  Then fetch `b`, finish filling `c`, and delete `b`.

Answer (score 3):

`hstack` is considerably faster:

```
a = np.ones((5, 2500)).astype(np.float32)
b = np.zeros((5, 5000)).astype(np.float32)
n = 5

%%timeit
c = np.zeros((n, 7500)).astype(np.float32)
c[:, :2500] = a
c[:, 2500:] = b
10000 loops, best of 3: 70 µs per loop

%timeit c = np.hstack((a, b))
10000 loops, best of 3: 27 µs per loop
```

If you use small arrays, `hstack` is a bit slower than the other solution.
In terms of memory usage both approaches should be similar.

Comment: Do you know which "bonds" do exist for hstack and the slicing approach? Like how small or how big has an array to be that hstack gets slower or considerably faster?